# Drawing criterias for PCB footprint

Tags: pcb-design, altium, footprint

I'm working with these two MOSFET [CSD18504Q5A](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/csd18504q5a.pdf) and [CSD18510Q5B](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/csd18510q5b.pdf?HQS=TI-null-null-alldatasheets-df-pf-SEP-wwe). With Altium I need to design their PCB footprint, but their datasheets in the section "Recommended PCB footprint" for each dimension they provide a minimum and a maximum. How can I draw the footprint using max and min? Which are the design criterias?

Comment: Use whatever lies inside these values and works with all your other design constraints too

Answer (score 2):

Here's the recommended layout for your first part:
[image]

The two values for each dimension are not minimum and maximum, they are metric and "customary" units (inches).

Use the metric values if you are designing in metric, and the inch values if you are designing in inches.